# Issue with [string lastPathComponent]

Tags: ios, nsstring

I want to extract the name of a file from a string like this

```
C:\IBM\...\images\custom\fileName.png
```

But

```
[string lastPathComponent];
```

gives me the whole string instead of fileName.png. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe `lastPathComponent` splits based on forward slash "/", your path contains only backslashes "\"

You can try replacing your backslashes:

```
[path stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\\" withString:@"/"].lastPathComponent;
```

Comment: Wow, I'm blind. Works great! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In addition to michaels answer, you could also do the following.

```
NSArray *listItems = [string componentsSeparatedByString:@"\\"];
NSString *endOfString = [listItems lastObject];
```

as long as the string is not an empty or nil string, this will work.

Answer (score 1):

And one other alternative to the other fine answers:

```
NSString *path = @"C:\IBM\...\images\custom\fileName.png";
NSRange backslashRange = [path rangeOfString:@"\\" options:NSBackwardsSearch];
NSString *filename = [path substringFromIndex:backslashRange.location + 1];
```

Of course this should have proper checking that the string actually has a backslash.

FYI - not that it matters if done on one or just a few strings but this approach is more efficient than the other answers because this approach doesn't needlessly process the whole string or create extra copies.

Comment: for anyone wondering, the check being alluded to is backslashRange.location != NSNotFound IIRC. All our answers assume the original poster is making sure the string is actually the path he is looking for.